# jquery - How to get the value of an element by class?

Tags: jquery

I have here a list of items in a table. Each item has a "Select" button on the right. Whenever the user clicks the "Select" button the item or text on the left of the button should display on the `span`. What happens is when I click the "Select" button all the items is being displayed on the `span`.

To see the actual scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/HnAnu/

My code is down below:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.7.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   $(".btnSelectItem").click(function () {
    $("#spanItemDescription").html("<u>"+$(".tdItemDescription").text()+"</u>");
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <span>Item: </span>
  <span id="spanItemDescription">____________________________</span>
 </div>
 <table border=1>
  <tr>
   <td class="tdItemDescription">Shin Guard Small</td>
   <td><input type="button" class="btnSelectItem" value="Select"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="tdItemDescription">Shin Guard Medium</td>
   <td><input type="button" class="btnSelectItem" value="Select"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="tdItemDescription">Shin Guard Large</td>
   <td><input type="button" class="btnSelectItem" value="Select"/></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: glad that you find a solution.please mark it as answer , so every one knows which answer will let you solve this issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
  $(function() {
            $(".btnSelectItem").click(function () {
                $("#spanItemDescription").html("<u>"+$(this).parent('td').siblings('.tdItemDescription').text()+"</u>");
            });
        });
```

[​FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HnAnu/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You just have to get the right td

```
$("#spanItemDescription").html("<u>"+$(this).parent('td').prev(".tdItemDescription").text()+"</u>");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HnAnu/1/)

Comment: Thanks it worked but islandmyth answered first by split seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
        $(".btnSelectItem").click(function () {
            var text = $(this).parent().prev().text(); //the previous node of the parent of button
            $("#spanItemDescription").html("<u>"+text+"</u>");
        });
    });
```

This works :)